# Impossible to pack Circles without gaps

Tags: geometry, circles, packing-problem

It is intuitively apparent that circles cannot be packed without any gaps. I thought this is easy to prove, but it turns out not to me.

I have $2$ versions for this question, which likely to have opposite answers.

$1:$ Is it possible to pack finitely many circles(of radius larger than 0) in the same size within a finite region.

$2:$ is it possible to pack circles(of radius larger than 0) within a finite region. (Which means we can shrink the size of the circle as small as we want and there can be infinitely many of them).

For $1$, I thought it is obviously impossible, since no matter how we arrange the circles, there is always some rooms not included within the circles. I thought it is easy to prove until I realise that there can be more way than I thought to arrange the circles. (see the pictures: or maybe this is already a proof?) [image]

For $2$, I think this is possible, just like pack any shape by rectangles like Riemann Integral, But I have not came up with a proof.

I think these are not obvious questions and need some tools, which geometrists may have but I do not. Any ideas and suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: It was proven by Thue that hexagon packing is best. Here is a paper about it: [arxiv:1009.4322](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.4322.pdf). A packing with no gaps (like you suggested) has density $1.0$, but the optimal density is closer to $0.9$.

Comment: Are you trying to pack with circles of *equal* radius, or are you allowing circles of various radii?

Comment: for 1, only equal radius. for 2, radius can be different as stated. @BarryCipra

Comment: [Apollonian gaskets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_gasket) are neat ways to fill circles with infinitely-many smaller circles. In general, [circle packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing) (and broader [packing problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems)) makes for a whole fascinating area of mathematics.

Comment: thank you guys very much for your information, I will study them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put in any first circle C. Notice if you have a finite number of circles there is not way to contain every point in the neighborhood of a point on the circumference of C.
2. Check out this link: [Filling a rectangle with an infinite amount of circles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2562960/filling-a-rectangle-with-an-infinite-amount-of-circles)

Comment: for 2, I suppose the circle is not of 0 radius? otherwise, 1 and 2 will be obvious. and if a circle is of radius 0, it has no regions and unable to fill any region?

Comment: Thats fair, I edited my answer to reflect my new understanding of the question